# Why can't @PostConstruct and @Retryable be used together?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-aspects, spring-retry

I have created a spring framework based application using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

One bean has an init method which creates a connection to an external service. This can be annotated with `@PostConstruct` to run automatically once the bean is initiated which works.

To handle any exceptions when creating this connection I want my init method to retry up to 5 times if an exception is caught. When annotating the method with both `@PostConstruct` and `@Retryable` I see the exception is thrown once and the program exits- It appears `@Retryable` has no effect.

I have used `@EnableRetry` in the configuration class correctly along with `@Configuration`. I have created another method B on the same bean which is annotated as retryable, if this method is called after the bean is instantiated I can see the method gets retried/behaves as expected when an exception is thrown.

My thoughts as to why this is not working is possibly something aspect related or the the postconstruct happens before the spring-retry element gets attached?

Is there actually a better way to have an initialization method that can handle exceptions and be retryable via annotations- instead of trying programmatically in the method?

Edit: I agree now that creating connections to external services should not be done via `@Postconstruct`. This can stop the whole context from initialising if the retries fail which can have detrimental effects.

However this does not yet answer the question of what part of the Spring Framework is not letting these two annotations work in conjunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'@Retryable' is an aspect applied by 'spring-retry'. This only attaches after the spring context is fully created, which is after all '@PostConstruct' annotated methods run thus the '@Retryable' has no effect.

Comment: I think a better answer is the below https://stackoverflow.com/a/38175918/1470436

Comment: @BetoNeto, the easiest answer to any problem is to stop having that problem. I think the best answer is the one provided by the OP since he explained the internal parts. Now it's up to the reader to use what he thinks is better with all equipped knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

> To handle any exceptions when creating this connection I want my init method to retry up to 5 times if an exception is caught.

You should NEVER connect to resources in init methods; you should wait for the context to be created first.

It's much better to implement `SmartLifecycle` and connect in `start()`. That way, you can be sure that the whole context has been initialized before you start connecting to external resources.

That way, the `start()` method should be advised by the retry interceptor.

As @Naros suggested, the `ContextRefreshedEvent` is another alternative but you should, never, never do stuff like that in `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Thanks for advice, Gary. But what to do next ? `connect in start()` – how to pass this connection then to specific bean? Before I read your answer I had been wanted to get connection (in my case: curr hazelcast instance) in `PostConstruct` with 5 tries.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments. Just move the code from the post construct method to `SmartLifecyle.start()`. If that's not enough information, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you actually apply an `ApplicationListener` that listens for a `ContextRefreshedEvent` and have this method annotated with your retry logic.  These listeners are fired once the context is fully refreshed and all beans have been properly configured and wired.

Comment: Replacing PostConstruct with EventListener({ContextRefreshedEvent.class}) in combination with Retryable gives the behavior I want. I believe the Context can be refreshed more than once in an applications lifecycle so it may not be the solution I am looking for. The Method to create the connection should only ever run once with X retries.

Comment: Yes a context can be refreshed multiple times, but during each refresh beans are recreated in the spring context, so it should give you the behavior you want regardless.